# Visual Basic, Copying Success but does not Insert data into SQL TABLE

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have some problems here. I need help.

Recently, I have created a local database called *stock.mdf* and the application will be getting all the data from the hosting MySQL database into this local SQL Server database.

I am using `sqlBulkCopy` to inserting all the data. I have tried to view it after inserting. But when I close my application, I head back to check the table data. It does not inserted. Why is that?

Here is my code:

Here will be retrieving the data from the hosting

```vb
    Dim connStr As String = "server=xxxx;user=xxx;database=xxx;password=xxxx;"
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim Adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim StockData As New DataTable

    Try
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM stock"
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MYSQL.....")
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = SQL

        Adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        Adapter.Fill(StockData)

        ' StockViewGrid.DataSource = StockData
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())

    Finally
        conn.Close()
        Console.Write("Done")
    End Try
```

This will be the places where `sqlBulkCopy` working:

As well, I am trying to view from the *stock* table.

```vb
 Dim Local_connectionStr As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|stock.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim Local_conn As New SqlConnection(Local_connectionStr)
    Dim Local_cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim Local_Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim Local_StockData As New DataTable

    Try
        Using sqlBulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(Local_conn)
            'Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "stock"

            '[OPTIONAL]: Map the DataTable columns with that of the database table
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("stockId", "stockId")
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("id_android", "id_android")
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("itemCode", "itemCode")
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("quantity", "quantity")
            Local_conn.Open()
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(StockData)
            Local_conn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())

    Finally
        Local_conn.Close()
        Console.Write("Done")

    End Try


    Try
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM stock"
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MYSQL.....")
        Local_conn.Open()
        Local_cmd.Connection = Local_conn
        Local_cmd.CommandText = SQL

        Local_Adapter.SelectCommand = Local_cmd
        Local_Adapter.Fill(Local_StockData)

        StockViewGrid.DataSource = Local_StockData
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())

    Finally
        Local_conn.Close()
        Console.Write("Done")

    End Try
```

Comment: iirc there is some issue around using a local MSSQL db to do with it being copied into your dev folder when you run in debug, and then the results being discarded on exit. (Hopefully someone with a better recall of this issue will be along soon!)

Comment: hmm ok, I try and find somemore info while waiting someone to help me solve it

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment (not enough points) I will put my thoughts here. Can you check that you got the expected data with a

```
Console.WriteLine(StockData.Rows.Count.ToString)
Console.ReadLine()
```

Also, your destination table doesn't have a PK that is auto increment, does it?
Sorry about the comment as an answer. (Untested code)

Comment: yes it does have A.I .Hmm seems not my code problem

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your code extracts are lacking headers etc, so are not complete, and I cannot be absolutely certain, BUT in your retrieving routine you seem to be declaring StockData as a local variable.  This means that, although this may well be being filled with the data from MySQL, it is immediately discarded on exiting from this routine.  Therefore the StockData variable in the sqlBulkCopy routine will be empty, and therefore will insert nothing.  You need to fix your scope and make sure that the StockData read from MySQL is the same StockData used in SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: yup it is the same i tried in sqlserver management it works tho. But when i try for my test project in a stock.mdf local database. It wont be working